# Android crop action getData null with some device

Tags: android, android-crop

I have a problem when cropping image with activity result. I have set permission on device >6. But when show crop and crop is successful, the result data is null. (`imageReturnedIntent.getData()` us null and intent data is also null). It is code crop image.

```
public static Intent cropIntent(Uri inUri, int outputX, int outputY,
                                    boolean isScale) {
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(inUri, "image/*");
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", outputX > 0 ? outputX : 100);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", outputY > 0 ? outputY : 100);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", outputX > 0 ? outputX : 100);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", outputY > 0 ? outputY : 100);
    cropIntent.putExtra("scale", isScale);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "img.jpg");
    Uri mCropImagedUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    cropIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCropImagedUri);
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    return cropIntent;
}
```

It is code activitysult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    if (callbackManager != null) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    }

    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Uri uriImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                System.out.println(">>>> uri "+uriImage);
                //   CommonUtils.cropImage(uriImage,HomeActivity.this,SELECT_CROP_IMAGE);
                startActivityForResult(CommonUtils.cropIntent(uriImage,
                        200, 200, true), SELECT_CROP_IMAGE);
            }
            break;
        case SELECT_CROP_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //   Uri uri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

                System.out.println(">>>>> "+imageReturnedIntent.getData());
                Bundle extras = imageReturnedIntent.getExtras();
                if (extras == null) {
                    System.out.println(">>>>> check intent");
                    return;
                }
                // Bitmap bitMapScale = extras.getParcelable("data");
                Uri uri = extras.getParcelable(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
                try {
                    Bitmap bitMapScale = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
                    System.out.println(">>>>>> check " + bitMapScale);
                    //       yourSelectedImage.recycle();
                    // base64
                    String myBase64Image = CommonUtils.encodeToBase64(bitMapScale, Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100);
                    //   bitMapScale.recycle();
                    assert uri != null;
                    LocalStorage.getShareInstance().saveUriAvatar(uri.toString());
                    LocalStorage.getShareInstance().saveBase64Image(myBase64Image);
                    UserModel userModel = LocalStorage.getShareInstance().getUserLogin();
                    if (userModel == null) {
                        // if user have not login.
                        if (uiLeftMenu != null) {
                            uiLeftMenu.fillImage(uri);
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(">>>>>> check data");
                        if (CommonUtils.isStringDataValid(myBase64Image)) {

                            upLoadImageToServerWithStringBase64(myBase64Image);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            break;
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Sometime default crop is not working. You can use this library https://github.com/biokys/cropimage/tree/master/simple-crop-image-lib

Comment: `com.android.camera.action.CROP` is not officially supported, and is OK not to work. So there is no solution for it. Event not all devices support it.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem on Huwai device. Some device don't sent destination Uri via `intent.getData()`. But after some debugging i found out that the uri is set on `mAction` String variable  and it can be accessed via `intent.getAction()` method. Then you can generate Uri with 'Uri.parse(outPutFilePath)' this method. You can first check `intent.getData()` is null or not. If null then use `intent.getAction()` method to get Uri as string and generate output Uri.
I solved my problem this way. Hope this will help.